# How to find the average of numbers being input, with 0 breaking the loop?

Tags: python

I just need to figure out how to find the average of all these input numbers by the user while using 0 as a exit of the loop.

I need to figure out how to eliminate using 0 as part of the average. example: 5, 0, 5 ,5... the average is 5 by eliminating the 0.

```
nA = 1
nSum = 0
print ('enter numbers to find the average')
print ('enter 0 to quit.')
while nA !=0:
    nA = input ('gemmi a number:')
    nSum+=nA
   dAvg = nSum

print 'the total amount of numbers is' , nSum ,
print 'your average is' , dAvg ,
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `input()` allows arbitrary code execution, use `int(raw_input())` instead.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. Do you want to break the loop when '0' is input or just skip the zeros?

Comment: -1 If 0 exits the loop how can `5, 0, 5 ,5... ` be possible?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Only in Python 2. In Python 3, `raw_input` was removed, and `input` took on the behavior of the old `raw_input`. But the advice to pass its return value to `int` in this case is still sound.

Comment: @chepner: the code is obviously Python 2 (it uses `print` statement that is removed in Python 3)

Comment: Good point; I saw (what looks like) a pair of calls to the `print` function at the beginning of the script, and didn't pay much attention to the end.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you need to keep a counter which tells you how many numbers the user has input so you can divide by it to get the average (being careful not to count the final 0).  As an aside, the user can never put in `5,0,5,5` here because at the first 0, the loop will break and the other 2 5's won't have an opportunity to be input.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do average is to track "sum" of all the numbers and "# items" and divide the two when you're done.

So something like this:

```
nCount = 0
nSum = 0
nA = 1
print ('enter numbers to find the average')
print ('enter 0 to quit.')
while nA != 0:
    nA = input ('gemmi a number:')
    if nA != 0:
      nCount = nCount + 1
      nSum = nSum + nA

dAvg = nSum / nCount
print 'the total amount of numbers is' , nCount
print 'your average is' , dAvg
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want to do: Do you want to use 0 as the condition to exit the loop, or do you just want to skip all the zeros?

For the first case (which I understand from the title of your question), can be done something like this:

```
total = 0
nums = 0
readnum = None
print("Enter numbers to find the average. Input 0 to exit.")

while readnum != 0:
    readnum = int(raw_input('>'))
    total = total + readnum
    if readnum != 0:
      nums = nums + 1

print 'total amount of numbers is %d' % (nums)
print 'avg is %f' % (float(total)/nums)
```

The `float` on the division is needed otherwise the division is done only using the integer parts (e.g. the average of 1, 3 and 4 will give 2, not 2.66667).

It should be simple enough to adapt for the second case.